# Use of Mean Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

**Question**

Let $f$ be continuous on $[0, 1]$ and differentiable on $(0, 1)$ such that $f(0) = 1$ and $f(1) = 0\ $.

(i) Show that there exists $c$ in $(0, 1)$ such that $f(c) = kc\ $, where $k$ is a positive constant.

(ii) Show that there exist $a$ and $b$ in $(0, 1)$ such that $cf'(a) + (1 - c)f'(b) = -1\ $.

---

**My working**

I believe I am able to show (i).

Consider $g(x) = f(x) - kx\ $, where $k$ is a positive constant.

$\implies g(0) = 1 > 0$ and $g(1) = -k < 0\ $.

By IVT, $\exists\ c \in (0, 1)$ such that $g(c) = 0\ $.

$\implies f(c) = kc\ $, where $k$ is a positive constant.

---

However, I am not sure how to go about (ii), although I have a hunch that it requires MVT and may be linked to (i). Any help/suggestions on how to work (ii) will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Is $c$ in $(ii)$ same as that $c$ in $(i)$? Or do we know anything about it?

Comment: @VIVID I suppose so! I believe I have solved it. Haha. It would be my first time answering my own post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved (ii)!

By MVT, $\exists\ a \in (0, c)$ and $b \in (c, 1)$ such that $f'(a) = \frac {f(c) - f(0)} {c - 0} = \frac {kc - 1} {c}$ and $f'(b) = \frac {f(1) - f(c)} {1 - c} = \frac {-kc} {1 - c}\ $.

$\implies cf'(a) + (1 - c)f'(b) = -1\ $.

I am so happy :-)

Comment: Almost congratulations. You don’t have it quite right. Can you fix it?

Comment: Your first sentence should be: Apply the MVT on $[0,c]$ and on $[c,1]$. Then ... ?

Comment: Well, I'm not just picking on style. There's a big issue with quantifiers.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from. Is it better now?

Comment: There you go!  But leave out “let $a<b$” — this sentence again chooses $a,b$ ahead of the action.